# Hacker Typer style application for Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey, screencasts

I need to do a bunch of screencasts that demonstrate some programming techniques. I already know what I'm going to type for each of them, and I'd like to minimize all the delays and awkwardness from typos and trying to think what I was supposed to do next.

Is there a software that lets me paste a chunk of text into a buffer and then randomly mash at keys and have my buffer be output into the currently active window one character at a time? Kind of like a native customizable [Hacker Typer](http://hackertyper.net/). Could it be done with some kind of AutoHotkey script or something similar? Suggestions for applications for other platforms are welcome if none exist for the Windows platform.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to have to mash the keyboard, right? You don't just want the chunks of text to instantly appear?

Comment: Yes, I want one character to appear each time I press any key. When I pause, the output should pause as well.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write the AutoHotKey script for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). I'm sure somebody else could whip this up in no time, but I can at least imagine a possible structure to the script:

1. Define a [Suspend hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm) and start suspended, so that you can use your keyboard when you don't want to be mashing. Alternatively, or in addition, use [#IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) to restrict the mashing-keys function to the one window within which you will be doing this.
2. [Read a plain-text file](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileRead.htm) into memory.
3. Stack multiple [hotkey definitions](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for pretty much every key on the keyboard for your one script action.
4. Use [StringLeft](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringLeft.htm) and [StringTrimLeft](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringTrimLeft.htm) to retrieve a single character from your big variable and delete it from the variable.
5. Use [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) to send the character that you grabbed. You may need to do a little replacement or conditional to handle sending `{Enter}` and `{Tab}`, but maybe not.

Here's my script:

```
#UseHook        ; Avoid loops of the Send command triggering the hotkey again.
AutoTrim, Off   ; Don't auto-trim spaces and tabs from the beginning and end of the sourcetext.
SendMode InputThenPlay  ; Try to prevent the user from corrupting the buffer text.

Suspend, On     ; Start suspended

FileRead, MasherBuffer, magic-button-masher-text.txt
if ErrorLevel
    MasherBuffer = Type or paste text here. You can also drag-and-drop text files here.

Gui, +Resize +MinSize400x200
Gui, Add, Text,, When you are ready, un-suspend this script (Ctrl and `` together will toggle the suspension).`nType any character on the main QWERTY keyboard to send the characters from the buffer instead.
Gui, Add, Edit, vMasherBuffer, %MasherBuffer%
Gui, Show,, Magic Button Masher Buffer
Return

GuiSize:
if ErrorLevel = 1  ; The window has been minimized.  No action needed.
    return
; Otherwise, the window has been resized or maximized. Resize the MasherBuffer control to match.
NewWidth := A_GuiWidth - 20
NewHeight := A_GuiHeight - 50
GuiControl, Move, MasherBuffer, W%NewWidth% H%NewHeight%
return

GuiDropFiles:
Loop, parse, A_GuiEvent, `n
{
    FileRead, AddToBuffer, %A_LoopField%
    MasherBuffer = %MasherBuffer%`n`n%AddToBuffer%
}
GuiControl,, MasherBuffer, %MasherBuffer%
return

^`::Suspend

!`::Gui, Show,, Magic Button Masher Buffer

;   #IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad  ; This limits the button masher to Notepad.
`::
1::
2::
3::
4::
5::
6::
7::
8::
9::
0::
-::
=::
q::
w::
e::
r::
t::
y::
u::
i::
o::
p::
[::
]::
\::
a::
s::
d::
f::
g::
h::
j::
k::
l::
`;::
'::
z::
x::
c::
v::
b::
n::
m::
,::
.::
/::
Space::
GuiControlGet, MasherBuffer
StringLeft, outbound, MasherBuffer, 1
StringTrimLeft, MasherBuffer, MasherBuffer, 1
GuiControl,, MasherBuffer, %MasherBuffer%
if outbound = %A_Space%
    Send {Space}
else if outbound = %A_Tab%
    Send {Tab}
else
    Send {%outbound%}
return
```

You can make this only work in Notepad by uncommenting the #IfWinActive bit.

I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> defined as a hotkey to suspend the script.

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly, aside from the GUI fixes and some adjustments for my Scandinavian keyboard which I'll probably be able to tackle with the help of the online docs. A thousand thanks for the help!

Comment: Ooh, hey, @Kaivosukeltaja, I updated my script before I saw your comment and acceptance. The updated script has a GUI and a few improvements (especially the "SendMode InputThenPlay"). I have a line in the format of `a::` for every key I want to remap. It may be as simple as adding a couple lines with the additional keys on your keyboard.

Comment: Righteous! I'd upvote again if I could. This is a great demonstration of AutoHotkey's power in the hands of someone who knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote out what Dane described. This should do the trick.  It reads in a text file, splits by line, then inputs the characters of that line one by one with a configurable delay.

```
FileRead, text, C:\test.txt
/* Alternatively:
text =
(ltrim
this is the first sentence.
sentence 2 here.
sentence 3 hello.
sentence 4 reporting in.
)
*/

pos := 1
StringSplit, lines, text, `n

^Space:: ; Ctrl + Space
    line := lines%pos%
    loop, Parse, line
    {
        SendInput % A_Loopfield
        Sleep 100 ; Adjust this for delay between keys
    }
    ++pos
Return
```

I wasn't too sure on the "mashing" of buttons, so I did not include anything in regards to that.

Comment: This lets the user input one line at a time, which is part-way there. You could do basically the same script, but StringSplit by character (just don't specify a delimiter). I was afraid that might be an extreme number of variables, but it might be fine too. Also, I'm imagining that he wants newlines added as he types.